# jersey 2.2 and Spring Security 3 dependencies?

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, jersey-2.0

I have a REST services implemented using Jersey 2.2 and would like to secure it.
I've benched Apache Shiro without any major issues.
Now I'd like to prototype the same thing ( basic http security ) with Spring Security 3.

The issue is that I'm really lost between the dependencies that are required in order to mix both frameworks. ( there is no spring-jersey for jersey 2.2 ).

So if someone could point me to a working sample illustrating any kind of spring-sec3/jersey2.2 integration in a maven project I'd really appreciate.

Thanks per advance

Comment: I have implemented a REST API as well. First I tried Spring Security with Jersey, but I had a hard time trying to make them work together, so I gave up and built my api using only Spring. I'm very happy with the results. The api has a couple of months of life now and is working gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was posted  I finally managed to make work, in one app :

- jersey 2.2
- spring sec 3.1
- guice 3.0

Relevant properties and dependencies sections from the maven pom.xml file :

```
<properties>
  <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <jersey.version>2.2</jersey.version>
  <guice.version>3.0</guice.version>
  <hk2.version>2.2.0-b14</hk2.version>
 </properties>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>${jersey.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>${jersey.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.12</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${guice.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
  <version>${hk2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- SECURITY (start) -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
 <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now in the web.xml file you need to take care of the filter order in order to make a peacefull interaction betweeb spring and guice :

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns   /javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Filter to secure Jersey (JAX-RS) services -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-  class>
</listener>    

<!-- fist arm the spring security filters --->
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<!-- then filter all URLs through Guice Servlet -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.whatever.myapp.inject.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- finaly define our rest app mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletContainer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
     <!-- Jersey would scan the specified package and register available    resources -->
          <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>org.whatever.myapp.interfaces</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.whatever.myapp.inject.CurrentResourceConfig</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServletContainer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

Note that if you wish to have a co-habitation between guice and hk2 injectors you'll need to : 
- pay attention to the hk2 version you're using (the one from the pom.xml works)
- pay attention to avoid using guice injection annotations outside of the Guice classes, use javax standards outside of the guice classes.

Finally you need to bootstrap the guice from hk2 with the following code :

```
package org.whatever.myapp.inject.CurrentResourceConfig;

public class CurrentResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig
 {
  @Inject
  public CurrentResourceConfig(ServiceLocator serviceLocator)
  {
      GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
      GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
      guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(GuiceServletConfig.getInjectorInstance());
   }
  }
}
```